# Sending HTML Email in php?

Tags: php

Here is the code.

```
$to = 'youraddress@example.com';

$subject = 'Test HTML email';
//create a boundary string. It must be unique
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\"";
//define the body of the message.
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
<?
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
$message = ob_get_clean();
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

I don't follow it well. expect someone can do me a favor.

1. Why should I generate a random hash?
2. Why I must add boundary string and mime type specification to header?
3. Why use ob_start();?

4.

```
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
 Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

What are those lines meaning? Could I delete them? Thank you.

Comment: You clearly don't seem to get what is going on here. Can you at least tell us why you need an answer here? Is something not working?

Answer (score 1):

1. Generating a random hash is to avoid it colliding with your content.
2. A "boundary string" tells the email clients where headers start and stop and where the actual email contents start. Since you want to send HTML email, you must specifically tell the email client it will be receiving HTML, not just any content.
3. Otherwise the HTML and stuff will be sent directly to the browser, ie, the user viewing your site. Instead you want to store the HTML in a variable and use it instead.
4. Content-Type tells the email client what [kind of content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) you are sending and how it is [encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset).

Of course you **cannot** delete them. It would be like sending you a PDF file without saying it is a PDF and without a proper extension - you won't know what to do with it.

**Note**

Emails, websites, anything which has a structure (including most files) usually are laid out in a structure of "header" and "body".

The header tells the file reader what to expect in the "body". The "body" is the actual content the reader should do something with.

Comment: ... and there is only one body. That's why you need MIME parts and delimiters when you need to send two or more things.

Comment: Exactly. All the different parts still make part of one body, even if the spec is convoluted enough to allow regular header clauses between parts.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain why the random hash is used here, but I think it is just additional safety to ensure a unique boundary string, preventing name collisions between parts.

As to the content-type: you need  to specify that to tell the mail client that it should render HTML, and to indicate that your message is multipart. Multipart means there's more than one part, in your case a text-based part and a HTML part.

The boundary part is used to separate the contents of one part form the contents of another part, and from the header.

Using the PHP Output Buffer (ob_start and ob_end_clean) is not necessary at all, you can also just enter strings using quotes or using HEREDOC. An advantage of using the output buffer is that you can end the PHP (using `?>`) and have your IDE help you writing HTML. Make sure to add `ob_end_clean();` though, it is not yet in your code.

Comment: You don't need `ob_end_clean()` after you use `ob_get_clean()`. They do the same thing except the get one also returns the content.

Comment: No, `ob_get_clean()` does not switch off the output buffering, resulting in any further output still being buffered (and flushed eventually). If you don't want output buffering (which I would find logical, since you started it explicitly for this purpose), you specifically need to end it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php Quote: *ob_get_clean — Get current buffer contents and delete current output buffer*

Comment: http://php.net/ob_end_clean Quote: _ob_end_clean — Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering_. Deleting the buffer using _ob_get_clean()_ does not switch off the buffering mechanism.

Comment: If there isn't any more buffers to write to, where will it write? :)

Comment: +1 What on Earth... (or on Mars, whatever) :) You seem to be completely right. But does it flush every output that comes next immediately?

Comment: For that I think you need to use `ob_implicit_flush`. But I wouldn't stay on this assumption. I would force a flush myself is I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to. It's just that it makes things easier: the delimiter must be a string that's not part of the mail content.
2. You need a boundary to split the message in parts. An e-mail message is nothing else that a stream of characters. You need a MIME type so the e-mail client can know what each part contains. Otherwise, it could not know whether it's HTML or not (or a JPEG picture, or a PowerPoint presentation...)
3. Honestly, it looks like an overcomplicate replacement for regular string assignments. Rather than doing `$message = 'Hello World!';`, it prints `Hello World!` to standard output and captures the standard output into a variable.
4. These lines mean that you are finishing one part of the message and you are starting a new one that contains HTML. You can delete them if you don't want to add another message part that contains HTML but... isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: ad 4. The content-type and encoding are not related to this, they state how the content is encoded.

Comment: **3.** No it doesn't send to standard output. That's why it's output *buffering*.

Comment: @Pelle: well, you are right if you consider `text/html` or `image/jpeg` to be encodings.

Comment: @Christian: I'm starting to hate this semantic nitpicking. How could it buffer an output if there were no output to buffer??

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was referring to the character set and encoding. (iso-8859-1 7-bits). `text/html` and `image/jpeg` are mime-types and do not have anything to do with encoding.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGVicario There is output to buffer, just the term 'standard output' (i.e. STDOUT) is used incorrectly here, since output buffering is preventing the data being sent to STDOUT. Ambiguous terminology, I guess.

Comment: @Pelle: What I mean is that you actually need to send something to STDOUT in order to capture it with output buffer functions. If you `ob_start()` and do not echo anything, the output buffer will remain empty. If you `ob_start()` and echo to STDERR, the output buffer will remain empty.

Comment: @Alvaro - You don't send anything to STDOUT. In fact, PHP is built to support SAPIs that don't make use of STDIO. What I mean is that `echo $s;` doesn't necessarily send anything to STDOUT, even with OB turned off.