# Sending an HTML e-mail with PHP?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send an HTML email with PHP. The body currently looks like this:

```
$body = "Hello," . "<br />" .  "<br />" . "We sent you an e-mail to confirm your account has been "
. "created." . "<br />" . "<br />" . "Thank you!";
```

Would that properly separate the lines? When I declare my headers, would I also need to use the same format for line breaking?

```
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";     
    $headers .= "From: donotreply@webmaster.net";
```

Would I have to switch those new lines at the end of each header from `"\r\n"` to `"<br />"`?

Comment: Don't build a mime email yourself, unless you're just doing this to learn mime. use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, both of which make sending an html email trivial.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+html+email

Comment: Zend Framework has a pretty good [mail wrapper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html) you can use as a standalone piece

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending HTML Email in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104279/sending-html-email-in-php)

Comment: You're overworking it. You don't need to concatenate with all those `<br />` just do `$body = "Hello,<br /><br />We sent you an e-mail to confirm your account has been created<br /><br />Thank you!";`

Comment: @AlexGidan If you're going to mark as a dupe, it's usually best to pick an already asked question with an accepted answer or a few with upvotes. The one you chose isn't a very good example. IMHO

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm applying this fix now - Should I still keep the `"\r\n"`s separating the headers?

Comment: Yes, keep the headers as they are.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay, I use `Test Mail Server Tool` to grab e-mails and then edit them in the text editor. It shows line breaks there which worries me, but I copied the e-mail and put it in an HTML interpreter and it turns out just fine. I can't really test it on a real e-mail, so does this mean it works? I think it does but I'm not sure. I feel it is just `Notepad++` interpreting it that way.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure it does work. I saved it as an `HTML` file and not as a `.eml` and then opened it in my browser and it works fine. As long as it will show like that in the e-mail (which it should since it is an text/html email) it should work. Thanks again Fred, always to the rescue haha.

Comment: I'd imagine it would. I'm not familiar with that server tool, so I couldn't elaborate on that.

Answer (score 1):

Is better using library but to have an idea try this:

```
function    sendemail( $to, $from, $subject, $title, $html, $cc = "", $bcc = "" )
    {
    $message  = "\n";
    $message .= "<!doctype html><html><head><title>$title</title></head><body>";
    $message .= $html;
    $message .= "</body></html>";

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from \r\n";
    $headers .= ( $cc != "" ) ? "Cc: $bcc \r\n" : "";
    $headers .= ( $bcc != "" ) ? "Bcc: $bcc \r\n" : "";

    return mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, "" );
    }
```